# Building DayTrader with Maven 3

Tags: apache, maven-3, geronimo

Has anyone attempted to build the Apache Geronimo DayTrader application with the latest Maven build?  When I try to follow the instructions here:

https://cwiki.apache.org/GMOxDOC22/daytrader-a-more-complex-application.html

I am getting numerous build errors:

```
[ERROR] The build could not read 6 projects -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.apache.geronimo.daytrader:daytrader-web:3.0-SNAPSHOT (C:\workspaces\sma\DayTrader\trunk\modules\web\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.apache.taglibs:taglibs-standard-jstlel:jar is missing. @ line 99, column 21
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.apache.geronimo.daytrader:json-proxy:3.0-SNAPSHOT (C:\workspaces\sma\DayTrader\trunk\modules\json-proxy\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.apache.taglibs:taglibs-standard-jstlel:jar is missing. @ line 55, column 21
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.apache.geronimo.daytrader:daytrader-web-jdbc:3.0-SNAPSHOT (C:\workspaces\sma\DayTrader\trunk\assemblies\web\daytrader-web-jdbc\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.apache.taglibs:taglibs-standard-jstlel:jar is missing. @ line 72, column 20
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.apache.geronimo.daytrader:daytrader-web-jpa:3.0-SNAPSHOT (C:\workspaces\sma\DayTrader\trunk\assemblies\web\daytrader-web-jpa\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.apache.taglibs:taglibs-standard-jstlel:jar is missing. @ line 81, column 21
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.apache.geronimo.daytrader:daytrader-webprofile-war:3.0-SNAPSHOT (C:\workspaces\sma\DayTrader\trunk\assemblies\webprofile\daytrader-webprofile-war\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.apache.taglibs:taglibs-standard-jstlel:jar is missing. @ line 112, column 20
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.apache.geronimo.daytrader:daytrader-war:3.0-SNAPSHOT (C:\workspaces\sma\DayTrader\trunk\assemblies\javaee\daytrader-war\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.apache.taglibs:taglibs-standard-jstlel:jar is missing. @ line 112, column 21
```

I am following the instructions exactly as they have them.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because the `<version>` information for `taglibs-standard-jstlel` project is missing. This will break not just in maven3, but in any other maven version as well.
This is likely a bug.

Comment: OK, thanks.  I figured it was something like that.  The problem is I'm using the code directly from the DayTrader trunk and its still not building correctly.  Any idea what version the latest DayTrader app should be using?

Comment: Just bumped into this. Maven 3.0.2 nagged about the issue while Maven 2.2.1 run through just fine. So there are some differences, though Maven3's stricter approach is of course better (I was doing something wrong anyway).